# MIPS Program to multiply two numbers

Tags: mips

I need to write an assembly program which multiplies two signed numbers (in
two’s complement system). The multiplier and multiplicand could be any number within the 8 bit data range and with any sign. Make sure your assembly program is generic.

Here's what I have but I get the error "program is finished running (dropped off bottom)" and I'm not sure why.

```
.data
str1: .asciiz "Enter a"
str2: .asciiz "Enter b"
str3: .asciiz "a*b = "

main:
li $v0, 4
la $a0, str1
syscall

li $v0, 5
syscall
add $s0, $v0, $zero

li $v0, 4
la $a0, str2
syscall

li $v0, 5
syscall
move $s1, $v0

mult $s0, $s1
mflo $t2
li $v0, 1
move $a0, $t2
syscall

li $v0, 4
la $a0, str3
syscall

li $v0, 10  
syscall
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've placed your code in the data section. Right before `main:` you should have a `.text` directive. You might need a `.globl main` too.

Comment: The `mars` simulator is forgiving. Without a `main`, it will start at the first location of `.text` [which isn't in the original code]. On the other hand, the `spim` simulator emulates a `jal main` to start the program [and, IIRC, `a0` is `argc` and `a1` is `argv`] and needs `.text`, `.globl main`, and `main:`. Without all this, `spim` will complain about an undefined reference, or some such